# Incompatible types when I used delete from the list in REST API

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, rest

I am trying to delete a list using username in spring-boot REST web service. My code block for delete method is,

```
@PostMapping("/delete/{username}")
public List<String> delete(@PathVariable("username") final String username) {

    List<Location> locations = locationsRepository.findByUserName(username);
    locationsRepository.delete(locations);
    return getLocationsByUserName(username);
}
```

and LocationsRepository as following,

```
import com.smartfarm.dbservice.model.Location;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface LocationsRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Integer> {
    List<Location> findByUserName(String username);
}
```

When I compile this program, I am getting the error as,

```
incompatible types: java.util.List<com.smartfarm.dbservice.model.Location> cannot be converted to com.smartfarm.dbservice.model.Location
```

Any suggestion/solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using `@DeleteMapping` and not the `@PostMapping`.

You need to use `deleteAll` method; `delete` is used for deleting a single entity. You can check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html).

Moreover, one good suggestion would be to make the return type of delete method as `void`. As your delete method is returning `getLocationsByUserName`, I assume it returns the locations with the same username as a result, which will be null anyway, you can make the return type as `void` and skip the method call to `getLocationsByUserName`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the same method for another program. It was working fine and returning output as empty list (i.e [ ]). But when I try this code for above program I am getting the error as I explained in the question. Is there any other possibility for this error?

Comment: I found this is because of different spring-boot version. As I mentioned before, the working program is older version which is 1.5.6 and new program is with new version which is 2.3.2. Thank you for your suggestion on this.